# I can post questions, but they don't show up on the front page or anywhere else

Tags: bug, status-completed, recent-activity

The front page and other question listings don't show any new activity.  I just posted [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/475657/how-quickly-do-i-need-to-complete-the-installation-of-windows-updates-once-they) and it doesn't show up on the front page or recent questions page.  I understand this may be due to the recent database migration, but can someone address this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Deltik said, this was a side-effect of the database migration that happened earlier today.

Should be fixed now. We just had to rebuild a few services that didn't get rebuilt after the migration took place.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is due to the recent database migration.  As far as I can see, all Stack Exchange sites are affected except for Stack Overflow, which was the first to come back to life.

Stack Overflow Meta was taken down to read-only mode momentarily, but when it resumed operations, like the other sites, it still did not show new activity.

**The only thing we can do is wait it out.**

Until then, there is an ugly workaround to check out the latest questions:

1. Select the question ID of the most recent question.  Example: [meta.superuser.com/questions/**5573**](https://meta.superuser.com/q/5573/83694)
2. Increment that number until you reach a newer question.  **5574** and **5575** lead to an answer because IDs are assigned sequentially not only to questions, but **5576** is the next-newest question, which doesn't show up yet on the front page.

I found this question by incrementing the numbers.

<sup><sub>This is the equivalent Meta Stack Overflow question: [Is my question (incorrectly) banned due to fighting with spam?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147246/188803)</sub></sup>

---

**UPDATE 03:12 AM UTC:** Uhp!  Just a couple of minutes ago, the most recent questions came back to life on Super User!  Now waiting on Top Questions and other Stack Exchange sites to be fixed...